# bootstrap tooltip overflow issues leading to slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am using Bootstrap's tooltip to display text against some of the buttons within the display page. Everything is working fine except that the display of the tooltip goes entirely below the footer. For e.g.

The click button highlighted in blue should give "add new record":

[image]

The image below shows the "add new record going below the footer instead of being displayed near to the button itself

Error image:

[image]

The CSS code goes something like this:

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1070;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
    text-align: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    line-break: auto;
    font-size: .875rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none
}

    .tooltip.show {
        opacity: .9
    }

    .tooltip .arrow {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline;
        width: .8rem;
        height: .4rem
    }

        .tooltip .arrow::before {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            border-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid
        }
```

The html looks something this

```
<div class="tooltip fade bs-tooltip-bottom" role="tooltip" id="tooltip785907">
<div class="arrow">
</div>
<div class="tooltip-inner">Add a new record
</div>
</div>
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

On which relative positioned element is the tooltip absolute positioned? I think that is the problem.
Can you show more of your HTML and CSS?

Comment: I have uploaded the CSS and HTML for your review. Appreciate your support.

CSS: https://pastebin.com/exZJKmky
HTML: https://pastebin.com/Gn6jSjLA

Comment: Sorry, but a lot of your HTML and CSS is redundant and not necessary. Can you cut it down to the HTML and CSS that are relevant?
My first insight is that I would apply a position: relative; to the card-body class.